# Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'ConsoleApplication5.Number' is less accessible than method 'ConsoleApplication5.number.setNo

Tags: c#

```
delegate  bool Number(int n);

public class Program
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
        Number n = new Number(set);
        number.setNo(n);
   }
   public static bool set(int x)
   {
        if (x == 5)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;

   }
}
```

**number is the class where the problem seems to be**

```
public class number
{
    public static void setNo(Number r, int num = 5)
    {
        if (r(num))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value Match");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value NotMatch");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN:

> Top-level types, which are not nested in other types, can only have internal or public accessibility. The default accessibility for these types is internal.

I.e. if you don't specify access modifier in top-level type declaration explicitly, `internal` is used by default. `internal` is more restricted than `public` (internal visible only within assembly where it is declared). So you have delegate `Number` which is less accessible than method `setNo` which accepts this delegate as parameter. That mean method is public, i.e. you can use it in other assembly, but it accepts parameter of type which is not visible in other assembly. Just add `public` to delegate definition:

```
public delegate bool Number(int n);
```

Further reading: [internal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) and [accessibility levels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx).